# How do I create a table of windows that I can scroll horizontally and vertically?

Tags: android, image, scroll, loader, universal

I want to do something like this:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Except I want to be able to scroll between windows containing images and text instead of images like the one used by AUIL. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your requirement. Let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: Second, there are plenty of resources available on the web. Just go and do Google about it, try to go with some solutions provided and then post it here if you are facing any issues in the implementation.

Comment: I have already tried googling it but haven't found what I'm looking for. I'm hoping someone more experienced like yourself knows what I'm trying to do.

Comment: No one would help unless and until you share what you have tried so far! Include those details and links whichever you have tried and played with.

Comment: Sorry maybe I should explain in more details, I'm not an Android programmer but a web programmer and I've created my site that can scroll vertically and horizontally using jquery/html5.  I'm looking to make this an android application and have looked at phonegap and cordova, but both seemed complicated to me.